# Durable Message Replay from Change Data Capture

Tags: streaming-api, change-data-capture

Given the following posts from Salesforce:

- [Message Durability](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_streaming_api_durability.htm)
- [Replay Events Sample:  Code Walkthrough](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_generic_vfp_walkthrough.htm)
- [StreamingReplayClientExtensions/java/CometDReplayExtension.java](https://github.com/developerforce/StreamingReplayClientExtensions/blob/master/java/CometDReplayExtension.java)

The way I'm understanding the behavior here is that during the connection to the /meta/subscribe channel, if I wish to replay prior durable events, I can use the following options:

- -2: All events from the beginning of what is available/stored
- -1: Everything going forward after subscription
- Replay#: A previous 'replay' value from a prior message as starting point

I'm trying to pass the map value *{ "replay": { "/data/ChangeEvents": -2 }* along when *{ "channel": "/meta/subscribe" }* connection is going out but it is not replaying the 3 days prior changes as noted in the documentation for change data capture.

Is this the correct way to retrieve change data capture events for the retention period?  I'm assuming I should see all events replayed after making the connection but nothing old is coming through, only new changes.

Comment: The document you mentioned say `events (pilot) for 72 hours` , Being pilot you have to raise a case with SF to get it

Comment: @PranayJaiswal - do you mind letting me know where it says pilot?  I'm unfortunately not seeing that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer for this but I was able to make it work. Here is how I did it:

First step was to add the replay extension to the bayeux client (please note that I am using C#)

```
var bayeuxClient = new BayeuxClient(endpoint, new [] {transport});
bayeuxClient.AddExtension(new ReplayExtension());
```

Next I added a listener to the meta/handshake channel. This is where I will do my subscriptions.

```
bayeuxClient.GetChannel("/meta/handshake").AddListener(new HandshakeListener(bayeuxClient));
```

The HandshakeListener implements the IMessageListener interface, so it has an OnMessage method where we can perform the channel subscriptions.

```
public void OnMessage(IClientSessionChannel channel, IMessage message)
{
    _bayeuxClient.GetChannel(channelName, replayId).Subscribe(new Listener());
}
```

You just need to find a way to store the replayId per channel so you can access it in the HandshakeListener's OnMessage method. I personally created a class that inherits from BayeuxClient and I added a `Dictionary<string, long>` which contains the channel name and its associated replayId. I then pass the instance of the class to the HandshakeListener who in turn passes it to all the channel listeners. When a message is received in a listener, I update the dictionary with the new replayId.

I still need to look into that because I feel there is an easier way to do this but it works. I tried hardcoding -2 and I received all the changes I had made that day, not just the new ones. I didn't try going back 3 days but I noticed the documentation is saying that this limit is for high-volume events as opposed to 24 hours for standard-volume events.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Richard, Which package are you using for _bayeuxClient or COMETD. Is there a link for sample Code or Document ?

Comment: @NSS I used CometD.NetCore --> https://github.com/kdcllc/CometD.NetCore

Comment: @RichardCormier: This might be a naïve question but does this .net client also captures Change Data Capture vents as well? or it only works for Platform Events ?

Comment: @SharpCoder it seems that it's the same principle for [Change Data Capture] (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_subscribe_emp_connector.htm). You just need to listen to the /data/ChangeEvents channel but I never tried it.